# Properly handle the deletion of an object only if there are no relationships?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a `Person` entity which belongs to a `Department` in a one to many relationship.

I would like to be able to delete the `Department` when there are no more `Person`s associated with it (either through the deletion of the `Person` entity, or a change to the `Person`'s `department` attribute). Right now, I'm trying to do so with the following handler for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` (Currently just trying to see deletions, and delete appropriately):

```
- (void)managedObjectDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    for (NSManagedObject *obj in updatedObjects) {
        if ([obj.entity.name isEqualToString:@"Person"]) {
            NSLog(@"Person Changed");

            NSManagedObject *department = [(Person *)obj department];
            NSLog(@"%i", [[department valueForKey:@"person"] count]);

            if ([[department] valueForKey:@"person"] count] == 0) {
                NSLog(@"Department has no more people associated with it");
                // deletion code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the count of the number of people associated with the department doesn't change when I delete a person. I am not performing a fetch on the `Department` entity. Is that something I should be doing?

Comment: Are you saving the context after deleting the `Person` object?

Comment: Yeah, I delete the `Person`, save the context, and when I `NSLog` the count of `Person`objects associated with the `Department`, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way: implement `willSave` in your Department entity class (You are giving each entity its own class, right? *), have your department check itself for `[self isDeleted] == NO` and `[[self person] count] == 0`, and delete itself if so. (The check of `isDeleted` isn't optional, because an entity changing itself inside `willSave` triggers another call to willSave. The docs for `NSManagedObject willSave` have more info.) This postpones the delete until the context is flushed back to disk, which shouldn't be a huge problem.

If you do need the Department to delete itself the instant the last person leaves it, have your Department entity observe itself with KVO. Register it as an observer on its own "person" property in `awakeFromFetch` and `awakeFromInsert`, and unregister in `willTurnIntoFault`. When the person property changes, check it for empty. This is more work, so only try it if the first way doesn't work for you.

Finally, remember that the Person->Department relationship delete rule needs to be set to 'nullify' (when Person is deleted, it is removed from Department's persons), not 'no action' (when Person is deleted, you take responsibility for cleaning up the Department yourself) or 'cascade' (when any Person is deleted, its Department is deleted too!)

(* MOGenerator is a very nice helper for maintaining per-entity classes. http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/ )

Comment: The only problem with using KVO to have the `Department` observe itself, is that it isn't listening when it is a fault. If the last `Person` object is deleted when it's `Department` is a fault, your object graph will be compromised.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Person` subclass, override `prepareForDeletion`. If the `Department` has only one `person` left, delete the `Department` too. Apple's documentation even suggests using `prepareForDeletion` as the best place to do custom delete propagation.

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion
{
    [super prepareForDeletion];

    if (self.department.persons.count == 1) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.department];
    }
}
```